# Is there a way to access Ethereum Smart Contract's variables by name in JavaScript?

Tags: ethereum, javascript, smartcontracts

Say I have a simple smart contract:

```
contract Simple {
    string32 message;

    function Simple() {
        message = "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

How can I easily access the `message` variable by name in JavaScript? It looks like [there is some way to map functions into JS](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/javascript-api-2/), but variables appear to only be accessible through [a complicated way](https://dappsforbeginners.wordpress.com/tutorials/javascript-api-1/):

```
var storageObject = web3.eth.storageAt(contractAddress);
document.getElementById('fullName').innerText = web3.toAscii(storageObject['0x']) + ' ' + web3.toAscii(storageObject['0x01']);
```

Answer (score 7):

Note that this question has been automatically mapped to [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3a8oi0/is_there_a_way_to_access_ethereum_smart_contracts/) and answered there.

If you declare your state variables as `public`, a function to read their values will be automatically created by the compiler ("[accessor function](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/Solidity-Tutorial#accessor-functions)"). If you use the [rich interface provided by web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract), you can create a javascript contract object and just call `message()` on that to get the respective value.

For arrays and mappings, the compiler will generate a function that has additional arguments which correspond to the indexes. For example, for a variable `mapping(uint => uint[]) public data;` the function will be equivalent to `function data(uint x, uint y) constant returns (uint) { return data[x][y]; }`.

Comment: Hmm, I tried using the `public` function. I added the function to the contract descriptor, but now that I call it, the javascript thinks I want to send a transaction to the contract to invoke that function...

Comment: Which version of web3.js are you using? The most current one should decide between a local call and a transaction automatically, with older ones you had to be explicit.

Can you post the JSON for the ABI for the contract?

Comment: @RobMyers I'm trying to run it in AlethZero v0.8.2 . My current test code is available at https://github.com/ThePiachu/EtherTest .

Comment: You seem to use an outdated solidity compiler. `string32` has been replaced by `bytes32` and also your interface json looks incomplete.

Comment: @chriseth Hmm, interesting. I will have to give a "cutting edge" version a go then...

Comment: @chriseth Can you explain what you mean about the "accessor function"?  I went to that link, and it's been moved, and the phrase "accessor function" isn't anywhere on the new page.  What I want is to access a string that I coded into a contract.  Preferably I want to see it on the blockchain explorer.

Comment: @stone212 the term was renamed to "getter" in the meantime.

Comment: Who pays the cost of reading that data and where does the request go? Is it something that ETH nodes have to provide for free?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out `web3.eth.contract` - it should have exactly what you need. https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethcontract

Answer (score 1):

Here is a JavaScript code for Node.JS to read a

- You need the contract Solidity source code to get ABI
- With this ABI and web3 convenience methods you can read the contract data

Example:

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
var solc = require("solc");
var fs = require('fs');

// Connect to a geth server over JSON-RPC
var web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://localhost:8545"));

console.log("Talking with a geth server", web3.version.api);

// Read standard token contract from https://www.ethereum.org/token
var sourceCode = fs.readFileSync('sol/token.sol','utf8')
var compiled = solc.compile(sourceCode);
var abiArray = compiled.contracts["MyToken"].interface;
abiArray = JSON.parse(abiArray);

// Create a proxy object to access the smart contract
var MyContract = web3.eth.contract(abiArray);

// instantiate by address
var address = "0x091cc7F4ACA751a6b8A4101715d6B07CD4232341";
var contractInstance = MyContract.at(address);

// All public variables have automatically generated getters
// http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/38079/5464
var result = {
  "totalSupply": contractInstance.totalSupply(),
  "symbol": contractInstance.symbol(),
  "name": contractInstance.name(),
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Comment: yeah! thank you very much! save me a lot of time! save my day!